# partitioned hard drive upgrade

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I want to upgrade my macbook pro retina early 2013 to 2tb ssd. Currently has a 256gb one. The drive is partitioned equally between windows and osx via bootcamp. If I take an image and restore on new drive, which partition will get the extra space?

Answer (score 0):

Neither one. If you clone the partitions you will get the exact same size partitions on the new drive with a bunch of unused space. You will need to extend the size of the partitions after you clone them over.

The problem you are going to run into is that you can only extend partitions that have free space after the partition. IMO It would make sense to clone whichever partition is first extend it to whatever size you want and then clone next one and extend it.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

Cloning software usually lets you choose if partition sizes should be preserved or adjusted. For example Clonezilla can resize partitions proportionally to fill a larger drive.